# What is the proper way to render a query result in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, rendering, drupal-7

I've generated a query, as follows, and formatted the results as links:

```
$result = db_query("SELECT name FROM {taxonomy_term_data} WHERE vid = :val", array(':val' => '1'));
  $list = array();
  foreach ($result as $record) {
    $list[] = l($record->name, 'blog/' . $record->name);
  }
```

Now I would like to render this array as an unordered list and return it to a block. What's the proper function/syntax for doing this?

Also, where is a good reference for functions related to rendering?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that "the proper way to render a query result" does not exist, there are many ways. They could be rendered as a list, as a table and many other ways. What you are asking for is the proper way to render a list of links, that these links are coming from the database is not relevant.

See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_links/7. And instead of calling theme() directly, you can also use the so called renderable arrays which are a new feature in Drupal 7 and the preferred way to do this now.

```
$result = db_query("SELECT name FROM {taxonomy_term_data} WHERE vid = :val", array(':val' => '1'));
// Prepare renderable array, define which theme function shall be used.
// The other properties match the arguments of that theme function.
$list = array(
  '#theme' => 'links',
  '#links' => array(),
);
foreach ($result as $record) {
  // Add each link to the array.
  $list['#links'][] = array('title' => $record->name, 'href' => 'blog/' . $record->name));
}
// Now you can call drupal_render() and return or print that result.
// If this is inside a block or page callback, you can also directly return 
// $list and Drupal will call drupal_render() automatically when the rest of 
// the page is rendered.
return drupal_render($list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it. Build `$vars` array and pass it to `theme_item_list($vars)`:

```
  $vars['items'] = $list;
  $vars['title'] = 'Sort entries by category';
  $vars['type'] = 'ul'; 
  $vars['attributes'] = array(
    'id' => 'blog-taxonomy-block',
  ); 

  $content = theme_item_list($vars);

  return $content;
```

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_item_list/7

Comment: You are calling the theme function wrong, this should be theme('item_list', $vars). Otherwise, this works too, yes but if the list contains only of links, there is no point to not use theme_links() directly.

Comment: @Berdir: Hmm.. theme_item_list() is part of the Drupal api [link](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_item_list) but using theme_links() is a bit more elegant.`
  $vars['links'] = $list;
  $vars['heading'] = 'Sort entries by category';
  $vars['attributes'] = array(
    'id' => 'blog-taxonomy-block',
  ); 
  
  $content = theme_links($vars);
  
  return $content;
`

Comment: Yes, but again, you must not call the theme functions directly, but with theme(). This defeats the whole purpose of the theme system (that those functions can be overriden by the theme).